# SimpleCursorAdapter загружает только видимые компоненты ListView

Tags: listview, android, java, cursoradaper

Использую кастомный адаптер, наследованный от SimpleCursorAdapter, все элементы отображаются нормально, но при нажатии, к примеру на первый, нажимается так же первый невидимый элемент, то есть position повторяется через такое количество элементов, которое вмещает в себя экран, в моем случае каждый тринадцатый элемент имеет повторяющийся position, поскольку до того как я начал использовать кастомный адаптер все было хорошо, то думаю что проблема именно в нем, если надо больше информации пишите в комментарии.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private Context appContext;
    private int layout;
    private Cursor cursor;
    private final LayoutInflater inflater;
    DB db;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,String[] from,int[] to) {
        super(context,layout,c,from,to);
        this.layout=layout;
        this.mContext = context;
        this.inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.cursor=c;
    }

    @Override
    public View newView (Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
            return inflater.inflate(layout, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super.bindView(view, context, cursor);
        ImageView marker = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.item_productiviry_img);
        TextView prod_tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvMarker);
        if(prod_tv.getText().length() == 10)marker.setImageResource(R.drawable.productive);
        if(prod_tv.getText().length() == 7)marker.setImageResource(R.drawable.neutral);
        if(prod_tv.getText().length() == 12)marker.setImageResource(R.drawable.unproductive);
    } }
```

Обработчик нажатия

```
lvData.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    final int position, long id) {
                m_pause.setClickable(true);
                ifpause = false;

                parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                item_name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvTextName);
                item_time = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvText_time);
                item_pause = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.mPause);

                if (oldId == position){
                    MainActivity.onStartClicked();
                    item_pause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    item_name.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.bottom_panel_icon_colour));
                }
                else {
                    if(oldId!=-1){
                        saveTime(oldId);
                        old_item_view.findViewById(R.id.mPause).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        old_item_view.findViewById(R.id.tvText_time).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        TextView old_tv_name =(TextView) old_item_view.findViewById(R.id.tvTextName);
                        old_tv_name.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

                    }
                    onResetClicked();
                    onStartClicked();
                    item_pause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    item_name.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.bottom_panel_icon_colour));
                }

                Log.d(TAG, "old position = " + oldId);
                Log.d(TAG, "position = " + position);

                creatingFlag = true;

                m_Item_name =(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTextName);
                m_textTime.setText((String) m_Item_name.getText());

                lvId = position;

                item_pause.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        MainActivity.onPauseClicked();
                        setmPauseVisibility(v, false);
                        int id = position;
                        refresh();
                        ifpause = true;

                    }
                });

                if (view!=null)item_time.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);

                oldId = position;
                old_item_view = view;
            }
        });
```

Дело не только в нажатии, для видимых елементов метод myAdapter.getChildAt(position) работает нормально, для остальных - NullPoiter

Answer (score 2):

В слушателе кликов надо ориентироваться не на `position`, а на `long id`, который содержит идентификатор записи в `Cursor` (точнее значение поля `_ID`)

Соответственно надо вытаскивать параметры записи по этому `id`

Comment: понимаю, у меня в классе с базой данных есть метод, который выдает правильный id элемента, все работает хорошо, о только для видимых элементов, проблема разпостраненная, но толкового ответа я не нашел, только понял, что проблема в адаптере

Comment: Вы сами то хоть поняли что написали? (facepalm)

Comment: Я только учусь, если бы я все знал, то, наверное, я бы не задавал вопросов. Если вы хотите помочь - я буду рад, если вы хотите поунижать новичка, то делайте это в другом месте пожалуйста.

Comment: Я и не собирался никого унижать. Я просто так и не понял ваш комментарий. Подробнее опишите ситуацию.

Comment: @Kolodach Вам нужно понять то, что если элемент списка "не видим" - то есть, по факту за пределами экрана, то у него нет позиции - его не существует в виде элемента списка. Соответственно нажать на него нельзя.

Comment: @KoVadim спасибо что откинулись, как заставить список обозначить все элементы? где-то писали что в методе onScroll() нужно заставить обновляться адаптер. Я прописывал notifyDataSetChanged(). в выше упомянутом методе - не помогло. Далее на stackoverflow нашел похожую проблему применяли ViewHolder я применил это в своем адаптере, ничего не помогло. Собственно, по этому я и решил написать свой вопрос буду признателен, если вы посоветуете решение, ибо уже все перепробовал

Comment: @Barmaley, как я понял вы предлагаете использовать ID колонку из базы данных вместо значения positon? У меня с этим возникали трудности, так как при удалении элементов из БД значения id заново не присваивалось и если я обращался к базе с запросом на id удаленного элемента я получал null. Поскольку опыта у меня очень мало единственное что я придумал - это сделать массив который включает в себя id всех элементов. Тогда я просто передавал методу position а он возвращал _id, ничего получше в голову мне к сожалению не пришло. Извини, но пока я не понимаю как колонка _id может помочь?

Comment: @Kolodach у вас какие-то фундаментальные проблемы с пониманием вообще как устроен `SimpleCursorAdapter`. Он не загружает все элементы списка, а лишь по мере необходимости. Представьте что у вас миллион записей (что в общем-то вполне реально), но ведь нет необходимости читать все и сразу (это медленно и в общем то не нужно). Адаптер читает только то что необходимо сейчас для отображения при клике возвращая вам идентификатор (первичный ключ) записи. Что вам еще надо то?!